# Stop macro when it reaches the last sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to stop a macro when it reaches the last sheet?

I get a run time error at the end.

```vb
Sub ACT1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("B:B").Select
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next ws
End Sub
```

I tried

```
If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, you do not need to activate/select anything. But if you like activation, which in this context only consumes Excel resources, please try adapting the code as: `If Activesheet.Index <= Activeworkbooks.sheets.count then Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate`. You should use `ws` instead of `ActiveSheet` and do not select anything...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Your code fails because you are trying to activate the next worksheet from the current one so when you get to the end, there is no more sheets to activate.

```
Sub ACT1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws.Range("B:B")
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Only after using `.Value = .Value` the new format is really applied to the range. Otherwise, it will be used only for future  added data... Please, put it back and I will delete my answer. It is very similar, except this part which looks to be misinterpreted...

Comment: @FaneDuru Ah I see, my bad and thanks for the information. I put it back.